# constructor injection in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

what is the correct way to do constructor injection in angularjs for instantiating objects with a factory or a service and invoke in a controller?

Ref : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

If you could provide an example it would be really helpful.

Comment: Have you checked the rest of the docs? I'm fairly certain it has decent examples for nearly everything related to angularjs, maybe here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 0):

An angular service is a singleton, so whatever you attach to the execution context in the service (eg: `this.*`), is usable in the module it's attached to.

An angular factory is a little different. In an angular factory, you are going to want to return a handle to a factory that will run your constructor function.

[Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CPeXe3F1Gc2BJwVpHoRr?p=preview) demonstrating both of them.

If you are writing your own angular module, your services and factories would attach to the module the same way, except, you must then inject your module into the app module.

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myAppModule', ['ngRoute', 'myCustomModule'])
```

This will allow the `myAppModule` to then use all the services, factories, directives in `ngRoute` and `myCustomModule` (`myCustomModule` is any custom module you write and inject into your app).